# I want to hide characters in a quick manner. \phantom hides but also takes a space

Tags: phantom

For example

```
\begin{align*}
\Omega \phantom{\Omega..}(A\phantom{\Omega..})
\end{align*}
```

Prints: `O   (A   )`
I want it to print `O(A)` without resorting to

```
\begin{align*}
\Omega 
%\Omega..
(A
%\Omega..
)
\end{align*}
```

which is just terrible

Comment: Are you referring to the difficulty of adding proper comments to your code without resorting to "terrible" layouts? You can use `\gobble` instead of `\phantom` where you have `\makeatletter\let\gobble\@gobble\makeatother` in the preamble.

Comment: OH MY!!!! Ty!!!!

Comment: note gobble could be more directly defined without using latex internals by  as `\newcommand\gobble[1]{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\phantom`, consider something like `\gobble` where you add

```
\makeatletter
\let\gobble\@gobble
\makeatother
```

in your preamble. Note that the use of `\gobble` inside math mode is probably fine as spacing is corrected based on the surrounding elements. However, using `\gobble` as-is in text mode might result in unwanted/spurious spaces in the output if not used properly.